# jQuery mobile ajax requests writes "0" in body

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple jQuery Mobile app that right now gives me a headache. 
It is written in Ruby on Rails using the 'jquery_mobile_rails' gem.

When I switch page with a normal link jQuery will put a "0" inside my body. If I force the link to not use ajax everything is good.

There are no errors in my browsers javascript console, and right now I am totally blank as to what causes this error. It is my first jQuery Mobile app, so maybe this is just a very common mistake, but I have tried all sorts of things:
- changing stuff in my views
- using jQuery Mobile that I downloaded myself instead of the one from the gem

Any hints are very much appreciated :)

Comment: Considering showing a representative code sample. It's very difficult to determine the issue from your description alone.

Answer (score 1):

Argh I am stupid and blind - seems to be fixed now.
All my footers had the same data-id="foo1"

@ryan - had written a long piece of code/html for you to look at, but found the answer before hitting the update button.